# Limit category transclusion when using dynamically-generated categories in MediaWiki

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

At first I wasn't sure if a question on how to do something advanced in MediaWiki belonged here, but upon reading the faq and thinking about it, I decided that wiki markup is as much its own language as HTML and CSS, and if those questions are welcome here, then hopefully this is too! If I am wrong feel free to flag this question. *Update:* Well as evidenced by the 3 views this question got, I suppose that while perhaps it's within the rules of Stackoverflow, there might not be much expertise on the subject! I suppose I will need to take this question to the official forums (shudder)

---

### The problem

On a wiki I am setting up powered my MediaWiki, I have a Template that outputs among other things dynamically created categories. This means that the page that invokes the template will be categorized based on some of the variables passed to the template. The dynamically generated categories are inside `<includeonly>` blocks to prevent the template page itself from getting the categories.

The problem is that I then transclude *that* page on to other pages, which causes the categories to be transcluded as well, and now that third page has all of the categories of all of the pages it transcluded.

I want to somehow format the template such that the page that invokes the template will make use of the categories but any pages that transclude the invoking page will not inherit the categories.

### Example

Here's my best shot at an example of the setup. If this is inadequate I can provide links to my real-world example.

**`Template:Food`**

A page that takes a couple variables and outputs a highly formatted block that explains the food, including outputting a category based on the "type" variable.

**`Banana`**

This page invokes the `Template:Food` template with a few variables, including `type` set to `"fruit"`. The result is when the user views the "`Banana`" page they get a nicely formatted page with some basic information about the fruit. Furthermore, if the user goes to the `Category:Fruit` page, they will see the Banana page listed.

**`Banana Nut Bread Recipe`**

This is the problem page. On this recipe page, the author wants to transclude all of the pages for ingredients so that each ingredient is listed in its nicely formatted block. However, when he transcludes the `Banana` page using `{{:Banana}}`, the `Fruit` category is transcluded along with it and now the `Banana Nut Bread Recipe` page is listed as being in the `Fruit` category which is wrong.

Comment: Ouch! Only a single view before it fell off the front page! I might have to actually solve this one for myself!

Comment: Gah, I have the same problem. I'm so upset that there's not a workaround!

Comment: I assumed it would be `<includeonly><noinclude>[[Category:X1]]</noinclude></includeonly>` until I realised the `<noinclude>` is evaluated on the first transclusion too. I did get something [slightly more complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Markhurd/Sandbox&oldid=476231035) to _display_ `<noinclude></noinclude>` in the transcluded result (and the category is processed), but I couldn't get it processed in the next transclusion. (Specifically `Special:ExpandTemplates` shows the identical output as the first transclusion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to limit the includeonly info (the category) to only depth 1 transclusion. I don't think it's possible.

Possible solutions:

1- Don't put category info into the `Template:Food`. Just put it directly in each ingredient page or if you really must, create a `Template:Food_category` or similar. Then each page could have any number of `{{Food}}`s and the `{{food category}}`s would need to be explicitly put.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am pretty sure you are correct that it's not possible, but a part of me knows that there must be a tricky (but probably hacky) way to accomplish this. While it's not the answer I want, I'll accept yours if I don't get a better one today.

Comment: What a pity that this is the only solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

The Labeled Section Transclusion extension lets you tag parts of a source article with labels, and transclude based on those tags.  The tags can overlap, so that you have very granular control over what gets pulled through.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Labeled_Section_Transclusion

I would think that with Labeled Section Transclusion, you could transclude both the Type:fruit and the Banana description in separate transclusion statements on the Banana page, but only pull the description through to the Recipe page.